Suspend API not working on 'Created' Task Status in JBPM V6.4
TaskService.suspend(id, user) is used for suspending tasks status by taking the inputs as Task Id and User Id in JBPM V6.4.
But we have some tasks in Created Status which are not being considered by suspend API to mark it as Suspended.
Only Ready and Reserved status is changed to Suspend.
Could some someone please help us in understanding why Created method is not changed to Suspended?
I have checked the documentation and tried to customize the org.kie.api.task.TaskService;,org.kie.services.client.api.command.AbstractRemoteCommandObject;org.kie.services.client.api.command.RemoteConfiguration;
But there are many depended methods needs to be customized and code is becoming huge.
